# How to do inter communication between a master and detail component in Angular2?

Tags: angular

There is a [master-detail](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html) example on the angular2 site. I can't follow the pattern in my example below.

In my example I have three components **(1) customershome (2) customers and (3) customerdetails**. The **customershome** compose **customers** (master) and **customerdetails** (details). In the **customers** component, I can select a customer and the details of the customer should be displayed in the **customerdetails** component.

How can I do the one-way communication from the customers component to the customerdetails component?

```
<div style="display: flex;">
    <div style="width:25vw">
        <customers></customers>
    </div>
    <div style="width:75vw; margin:5px">
        <customerdetails></customerdetails>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<customers #customer></customers> <customerdetails [customer]="customer"></customerdetails>`

Comment: Are you suggesting exposing a *customer* property in the *customers* component and then use an *input* property of the same for the *customerdetails*?

Comment: I recommend communicating via bound objects. Maybe you have a details object on some customer object somewhere that you can bind to the detail component. I have a master detail scenario here that might illustrate the concept: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/recursive-treeview-in-angular-2.0 It's a treeview where a tree node can be a master for multiple child nodes. Different components, but a related concept from what I can tell.

Comment: @TGH I went through your example. It's a good example for a parent component composing child components. But I think I may need a different composition in my master-detail example. This is due to I may have hundreds of customers and it's details (when the user select it) can be retrieved reactively only.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's a simple app that uses a parent `<customer-browser>` component with  `<customer-list>` and `<customer-detail>` subcomponents.

http://plnkr.co/edit/aEjlwIKKhcErWAnIhY3C?p=preview

The browser itself simply accepts an array of customers as an *input*, and has an internal *selectedCustomer* property.

The list component accepts the same list, and exposes a "selected" property, and emits a *selectedChange* output event. This syntax allows two way binding, and that gets bound to the parent's *selectedCustomer* property.

The detail component simply takes an *customer* input which is bound to the parent's *selectedCustomer* property.

Comment: As a side note, this example does not work in Microsoft Edge Evergreen browser. But it worked in Google Chrome.

Comment: Understanding selected**Change** is the key here!?

Comment: The Plunk does not work anymore, but it is helpful nonetheless.

Answer (score 12):

Try this -

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  inputs: ['model'],
  template: `<h3>child</h3> 
    <div>{{model.prop1}}</div>
    <div>{{model.prop2}}<div>`
})
class Child {

}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [Child],
  template: `
  <h3>Parent</h3>
  <button (click)="updateModel()">update model</button>
  <child [model]="parentModel"></child>
  `
})
class App {
  parentModel = { prop1: '1st prop', prop2: '2nd prop' };
  constructor() {}
  updateModel() { this.parentModel.prop1 += ' more'; }
}
```

Comment: Well, you can emit an output event.

Comment: @Kanchan can you please give an example of emitting an output event? or may be a link to example?

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer that Kanchan wrote here is an output. You can find all the information about outputs here in the angular Documentation: https://angular.io/api/core/Output

```
  selector: 'child',
  inputs: ['model'],
  template: `<h3>child</h3> 
    <div>{{model.prop1}}</div>
    <div>{{model.prop2}}<div>`
})
class Child implements OnInit {
  @Output() outPutEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  ngOnInit() {
   this.outPutEvent.emit(true);
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [Child],
  template: `
  <h3>Parent</h3>
  <button (click)="updateModel()">update model</button>
  <child [model]="parentModel"
         (outPutEvent)="outPutEffectFunction($event)"></child>
  `
})
class App {
  parentModel = { prop1: '1st prop', prop2: '2nd prop' };
  constructor() {}
  updateModel() { this.parentModel.prop1 += ' more'; }
  outPutEffectFunction(event) { return event ? 'event true' : 'event false'}
}
```

This answer just demonstrates the communication between 2 components, and can complement the previous answers.