# Angular2 and Event Aggregator to communicate between components

Tags: angular

The following [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33966692/how-to-do-inter-communication-between-a-master-and-detail-component-in-angular2) shows how to develop a master-detail component in Angular2. Can we achieve the same component communication using Event Aggregator pattern? Using an Event Aggregator can save many bindings.

Martin Flower describes Event Aggregator pattern [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html). This is being used in [Aurelia](https://github.com/aurelia/event-aggregator) also.

Comment: I can't believe noone hasn't really done anything about this problem in Angular2, I'm coming from .NET world and it's frustrating to see it missing!!

Comment: The question was asked in 2015, so a lot has changed now in the world of Angular2. The path Angular2 has taken is to use ```RxJS```. The communication between components can be achieved with ```Observable```.