# Bidirectional data binding on a component input property

Tags: data-binding, angular, bidirectional

I am trying to make something work on angular2 and I am unable to find something about this behavior.

I have an application that implements a custom component like this one :

```
import {Component,Input} from 'angular2/core'
    @Component({
      selector:'my-comp',
      template:`<input type="text" style="text-align:center; [(ngModel)]="inputText"> <p>{{inputText}}</p>`
    })

    export class MyComp{
      @Input() inputText : string;
    }
```

And I am trying to do a bidirectional databinding on my `inputText` variable from my component like this:

```
<my-comp [(inputText)]="testString"></my-comp>
```

Where the `testString` is a variable defined in the `MyApp.ts` which contains a string. I want my `testString` variable to be modified when my `inputText` is modified by the user.

Here is a Plunker with a simple sample code : https://plnkr.co/edit/zQiCQ3hxSSjCmhWJMJph?p=preview

Is there a way to make this works simply ? Do I have to implements an Angular2 class on my custom components and overload functions in order to make this works like an `ngModel` ? Do i necessarily have to create a `inputTextChanged` variable of `EventEmitter` type that emit my data when it's changed and do something like this :

```
<my-comp [inputText]="testString" (inputTextChanged)="testString = $event;"></my-comp>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes you have to create an event emitter "inputTextChanged", and fire the event inside of your component. Then [(inputText)] should work as expected.

Comment: As a notice: there is no such thing as bidirectional data-binding in Angular2, but you can have a similar behaviour. http://victorsavkin.com/post/110170125256/change-detection-in-angular-2

Comment: Well according to the Angular2 Cheat Sheet from the official website : " <my-cmp [(title)]="name"> 
Sets up two-way data binding. Equivalent to: <my-cmp [title]="name" (titleChange)="name=$event">". So i think we can say that there is bidirectional data binding in Angular2.

Comment: @jornare, I think you/Savkin and David are both correct.  I believe Savkin is trying to make the point that there is no code in Angualr 2 to handle two-way data binding.  I.e., `[(something)]` is just syntactic sugar for one property binding and one event binding.  So Angular does not treat `[(something)]` as one two-way databinding, but rather as two one-way data bindings.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is explained in the Template Syntax doc, in the [Two-Way Binding with NgModel](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel) section:

> `<input [(ngModel)]="currentHero.firstName">`
>
> Internally, Angular maps the term, `ngModel`, to an `ngModel` input property and an `ngModelChange` output property. That’s a specific example of a more general pattern in which it matches `[(x)]` to an `x` input property for Property Binding and an `xChange` output property for Event Binding.
>
> We can write our own two-way binding directive/component that follows this pattern if we're ever in the mood to do so.

Note also that `[(x)]` is just syntactic sugar for a property binding and an event binding:

```
[x]="someParentProperty" (xChange)="someParentProperty=$event"
```

In your case, you want

```
<my-comp [(inputText)]="testString"></my-comp>
```

so your component must have an `inputText` input property and an `inputTextChange` output property (which is an `EventEmitter`).

```
export class MyComp {
  @Input()  inputText: string;
  @Output() inputTextChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

To notify the parent of changes, whenever your component changes the value of `inputText`, emit an event:

```
inputTextChange.emit(newValue);
```

---

In your scenario, the MyComp component binds input property `inputText` using the `[(x)]` format to ngModel, so you used event binding `(ngModelChange)` to be notified of changes, and in that event handler you notified the parent component of the change.

In other scenarios where ngModel isn't used, the important thing is to `emit()` an event whenever the value of property `inputText` changes in the MyComp component.

Comment: Update Angular4: In the child component it is no longer necessary to specify the EventEmitter output. This is handled by @input automatically.

Parent view:

<my-comp [(inputText)]="testString"></my-comp>

Child component:

export class MyComp {
    @Input()  inputText: string;
}

Answer (score 8):

I'll combine @pixelbits and @Günter Zöchbauer answers and comments to make a clear answer on my question if someone in the future is searching for this.

To make bidirectional data binding works on custom variables you need to creates your component based on the following.

MyComp.ts file :

```
import {Component,Input,Output,EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core'
@Component({
  selector:'my-comp',
  templateUrl:`<input type="text" style="text-align:center;"
     [ngModel]="inputText" (ngModelChange)="inputText=$event;inputTextChange.emit($event);">`
})

export class MyComp{
  @Input() inputText : string;
  @Output() inputTextChange = new  EventEmitter();
}
```

MyApp.ts file:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {MyComp} from './MyComp'

@Component({
  selector:'my-app',
  templateUrl:`<h1>Bidirectionnal Binding test </h1>
    <my-comp [(inputText)]="testString"></my-comp><p>
    <b>My Test String :</b> {{testString}}</p>`,
  directives:[MyComp]
})

export class MyApp{
  testString : string;
  constructor(){
    this.testString = "This is a test string";
  }
}
```

There the bidirectional data binding to the `inputText` variable works correctly.
You can comment the answer for a more beautiful or simpler way to implement this code.

Answer (score 1):

Your Plunker already contains the `EventEmitter`. The `@Output()` annotation is missing. To change the value call `inputTextChanged.emit(newValue)` (this also changes the value on `inputText`)

Comment: Yes Sorry, I am new to plunker and forgot to lock the plunker to the state i wanted you to see and continued my test on it so you saw my modifications.

Comment: Ho I just remembered and i don't know if you know it but at least from the beta version of Angular2 ".next()" is deprecated and you should use ".emit()".

Comment: Thanks! haven't seen that.

Answer (score -1):

What I do is use a property, so when I change the data the change is emitted automatically

```
private _data: AnyType;
@Input()  get data(): AnyType{
    return this._data;
}
set data(value: AnyType) {
    this._data = value;
    this.dataChange.emit(this._data);
}
@Output() dataChange: EventEmitter<AnyType> = new EventEmitter();
```

In html you will bind the property using [(data)]

```
<comp [(data)]="getData()"></comp>
```