# How to send data from one component to another component By importing module in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

How to pass value from one component to another component but the condition is that we can not define the component on **declaration** section of module. i can easily pass value using this.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {AddressModule}from './address/address.module';
import {AddressComponent}from './address/address.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AddressComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

in address component i can easily retrieve the value using **@Input** but this is creating problem in my case.

so i want to do this using this

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {AddressModule}from './address/address.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AddressModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But i am not able to recieve value in component can somebody please suggest me some solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - Using Shared Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251368/angular-2-using-shared-service)

Comment: i think we can pass value by importing module in appmodule.\

Comment: you can use either service or directive, but again they will have to be declared in some module

Comment: You can use `@input` check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088209/how-to-pass-object-from-one-component-to-another-in-angular-2

Comment: in my case i have created a address component and if i pass it in declaration it works perfect.But when i import it in a module. it doesn't work.