# Transfer the value of input (search bar) between non-child components Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a list of users with input filter.
 My app.component.html like this:

```
<header>
  <app-header></app-header>
</header>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <app-left-menu></app-left-menu>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Header is like

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="headerFilter">
  </div>
```

How can I use a headerFilter in my userList componenet?

I know about @Pipe and i try:

Pipe

```
   export class BuildPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform (values: any[], field: string, value: string): any[] {
    if (!values || !values.length) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!value) {
      return values;
      }
    return values.filter(it => it[field].indexOf(value) >= 0 );
  }
}
```

and UserList.componenet:

```
<div class="item" *ngFor="let user of users | build: 'firstname': filter">
```

but how should i transfer value from header input to userList?

Comment: you could use an injectable service, to move and store the value?

Comment: You can use `@Input` see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088209/how-to-pass-object-from-one-component-to-another-in-angular-2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass object from one component to another in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088209/how-to-pass-object-from-one-component-to-another-in-angular-2)

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047854/how-to-update-a-component-without-refreshing-full-page-in-angular/46049546#46049546

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all answers!

finally i use service

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class FilterService {
  headerFilter: string;

  constructor() { }

  public getFilter(): string {
    return this.headerFilter;
  }

  public setFilter(filter): void {
    this.headerFilter = filter;
  }
}
```

and search-box component in header

```
    <div>
  <input #input type="text" (input)="update(input.value)">
</div>
```

**searchbox.ts**

```
   update (value) {
    this.filter.setFilter(value);
  }
```

and list like

```
 <div class="item" *ngFor="let user of users | build: 'firstname': filterServ.getFilter()">
```

where build is name of pipe

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Input` decorator if there is parent child relationship between components. Else make use of `Services` or `BehaviourSubject`. These are the following approaches based on priority:

1. Using Services(Most Recommended) [ [**example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047854/how-to-update-a-component-without-refreshing-full-page-in-angular/46049546#46049546) ].
2. Using Behavior Subjects from RxJS library.
3. Use Redux for state management.
4. Using browser storage(session/local) but least recommended as prone
   to data security.