# Master detail view in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

Edit: Figured it out. I moved all the html in the body of `index.html` to `app.component.ts` and everything worked fine. Below answer is correct method.

My issue is that I have a ParentComponent which reads from a service, and posts the data to a sidebar. When you click an item in the sidebar it's supposed to post details about that parent in the main section of the page. Since it requires two different templates, I figured the solution is to use a parent-child relationship where the parent is the sidebar and the child is the detail part and I pass the data to the child to display. Does that sound right? Is there a better way to solve this? I've tried various methods but they all seem outdated as it uses `directives` which aren't in use any more.

Edit: the other question is not the same because the answer references `directives` which were removed in rc6 release of angular2. This question is post-rc6.

Edit 2: Added some code

index.html:

```
<header>
  <div class="content">This is a header</div>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="content">
        <parent-items></parent-items>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
      <div class="content">
        <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
        <child-cmp [id]="selectedItem.id"></child-cmp>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

child-cmp.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-cmp',
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() set id(n) {
    this.getData(n)
  }
  getData(id: number): void {
     console.log('triggered');
  };
}
```

parent.ts:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'parent-items',
  templateUrl: `<ul class="items">
      <li *ngFor="let item of items"
          (click)="selectedItem = item"
          [class.selected]="item === selectedItem">{{item.name}}</li>
      </ul>`,
})
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {
  items: Item[];
  selectedItem: Item;
  constructor(private itemService: ItemService) {};
  getItems(): void {
    this.itemService
        .getItems()
        .then(items => this.items = items);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getItems();
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do inter communication between a master and detail component in Angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33966692/how-to-do-inter-communication-between-a-master-and-detail-component-in-angular2)

Comment: the other question is not the same because the answer references directives which were removed in rc6 release of angular2. This question is post-rc6.

Comment: Directives are still part of angular2.

Comment: If you could include more information that'd be great. Everything I've seen points to directives being removed in rc6 and I can't them in the docs.

Comment: Just Google angular2 directive? Lots of docs. Pretty much everything extends from them, like components. Try https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

Comment: Those are attribute directives. I'm talking about the `directives` property for `@Component` which was deprecated and removed in RC6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds reasonable.  Suppose the parent component has a `children` array of identifiers

**parent template (sidebar)**

```
<div *ngFor="let child of children">
    <a (click)="currentChild = child">{{child.name}}</a>
</div>
```

When a link is clicked, it will set the current child. The main section would display the current child.

**parent template (main)**

```
<child-cmp [id]="currentChild.id"></child-cmp>
```

Use `@Input` in child to accept a new child identifier. When an identifier is set, you can populate the child with new data.

**child component**

```
/** Get details from server and populate local variables */
getData(id){
    this.http.get('/api/children/'+id).map(data => data.json()).subscribe(
        data => { this.name = data.name; }
    );
}

/** Executed whenever a new id is set */
@Input() set id(n){ this.getData(n) }
```

Comment: This makes sense, but I'm having trouble implementing this. Setting the id doesn't seem to trigger the `@Input`. I posted some code into the original post.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I just had to move all the html in the body of `index.html` to `app.component.ts` as the template code won't parse in index.html. So that was my issue, otherwise your method worked perfectly. Thanks!