# How to pass array between a master and detail component in Angular2 without directive?

Tags: angular, dialog

I would use [How to do inter communication between a master and detail component in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33966692/how-to-do-inter-communication-between-a-master-and-detail-component-in-angular2) to solve this problem but it's not allowed now to use directive. How to pass my array from first component to another?

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { MdDialog, MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-flashcards',
  templateUrl: './flashcards.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./flashcards.component.scss'],

})
export class FlashcardsComponent {
  dialogRef: MdDialogRef<MnemoDialog>;

  constructor (private router: Router,public dialog: MdDialog) {} //router in function

  mnemo = ['assets/images/family.png', 'assets/images/blood-m.png','assets/images/obrazek.jpg','assets/images/asdfas.jpg'];
  n = 0;

  myMnemo = this.mnemo[this.n];

  nextImg() {

      this.myMnemo = this.mnemo[this.n];
      n++;

    }
  }

}


@Component({
  selector: 'mnemo-dialog',
  template: `<img fxFlex="70%"  md-card-image src="{{ myMnemo }}">`
})
export class MnemoDialog {

}
```

Comment: i don't know, what you wanna do, pls describe a bit more detail

Comment: I need to have this data "assets/images/family.png" from first component, in second component using interpolation (myMnemo)

Comment: 2nd component has `@Input() myMnemo`, 1st component has `@Ouput()` public an event when nextImg call, for example. or using service, public event by using `Subject`

Comment: can you explain more on how to achieve that?

Comment: maybe I will do something like global array for all components? Is that possible?

Comment: I will do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158848/what-is-the-best-way-to-declare-a-global-variable-in-angular-2-typescript?noredirect=1&lq=1 and I will see what happens thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mnemo-dialog',
  template: `<img fxFlex="70%"  md-card-image src="{{ source }}">`
})
export class MnemoDialog {
    @Input()source: YOURDATATYPE;
}
```

And in your flashcards.component.html something like this:

```
 <mnemo-dialog [source]="myMnemo"></mnemo-dialog>
```

Or is this not allowed?

Comment: nah, not working, I dont use mnemodialog like this <mnemo-dialog [source]="myMnemo"></mnemo-dialog>, I call fuction inside flashcards for this component open() {
    this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MnemoDialog);

  }